# code=dumped, single=ABRT when try to run dotnet core application as service in ubuntu

Tags: .net-core, systemd

I have simple console application, I want to run application as service in ubuntu.
I have created `.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system` folder `HelloWorld.service` as below

```
[Unit]
Description=HelloWorld Application
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet  /home/prasadg/HelloWorld/dev/HelloWorld.dll

SyslogIdentifier=HelloWorld

Restart=always

RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after I saved file I have reload daemon with command
`systemctl daemon-reload`

then I have started newly created service `systemctl start HelloWorld`

it get started and nothing happens, after sometime, when I checked status using command `systemctl status HelloWorld` it shows error as below

```
HelloWorld.service - HelloWorld Application
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/HelloWorld.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: core-dump) since Tue 2022-06-28 21:20:13 IST; 4s ago
  Process: 28389 ExecStart=/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /home/prasadg/HelloWorld/dev/HelloWorld.dll (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
 Main PID: 28389 (code=dumped, signal=ABRT)
```

---

if try run directly with command as `/usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /home/prasadg/HelloWorld/dev/HelloWorld.dll` it runs successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A full log message would help more, but I guess you need to add a [WorkingDirectory](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#WorkingDirectory=) to your `HelloWorld.service`.

Answer (score 0):

From my side, I must delete all existing binary files from Working Directory, then re-publish and copy all new binary files to Working Directory.
And stop and start the process again.
It's working well. ^^